# Excel to XML in .NET3.5

Tags: c#, xml, excel

How to convert Excel file to xml file using .NET framework 3.5

Please tell the approaches

The format of excel sheet is xls and convert to standard xml format

Comment: You're going to need to be a bit more specific - at the very least to clarify whether this is the newer office 2007 format .xlsx or the older .xls format - the former offers more choices.

Comment: What kind of XML? Excel 2007 already uses XML as its default format so a little bit more detail on what you are trying to achieve would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) will let you open a workbook (xls or xlsx format), get the formatted text (such as $5.00) with the IRange.Text property or the unformatted raw value with the IRange.Value property. You can also modify values and recalculate if needed. You would need to use the .NET XML APIs to write out the formatted text or unformatted values to an XML file.

You can download a free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it yourself.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in various ways based on your requirement

1. You can read it like a database using `OleDbConnection` object to connect to the file and read data
2. You can use `System.IO.Packaging` to read office 2007 (xlsx) files
3. You can also use `Excel.Application` object model to read information from Excel

It really depends on your requirement what method is effective for you.